# models created are returning empty array

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, express, sequelize.js

I have created two modules in my express using sequelize with typescript but when I try to log the model using `console.log(require('../models'))` it's giving an empty array.

```
{ models: {},
  sequelize:
   Sequelize {
     options:
      { dialect: 'postgres',
        dialectModulePath: null,
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        protocol: 'tcp',
        define: {},
        query: {},
        sync: {},
        timezone: '+00:00',
        logging: [Function: bound consoleCall],
        omitNull: false,
        native: false,
        replication: false,
        ssl: undefined,
        pool: {},
        quoteIdentifiers: true,
        hooks: {},
        retry: [Object],
        transactionType: 'DEFERRED',
        isolationLevel: null,
        databaseVersion: 0,
```

can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/suksant/sequelize-typescript-examples to create my models.

Comment: Consider formatting your question/code. It's quite hard to read